# Thread messaging queue not getting filled with messages properly

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function that reads in files, groups them with some data and then puts them on a message queue to be sent over a socket by a thread:

```
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    ... read in files and sort numerically ...
roke_data = {"filename" : None, "byte_string" : None}
for filename in lst:
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        roke_data["filename"] = filename
        roke_data["byte_string"] = f.read()
        fileQueue.put(roke_data)
    fileQueue.join()
    exit()
```

My thread's run function:

```
def run(self):
    try:
        self.connect_socket() #connects to a socket on localhost
        roke_data = self.fileQueue.get_nowait()
        print "Sending file: ", roke_data["filename"]
        self.sc.send(roke_data["byte_string"])
    except Queue.Empty:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

I've run tests to confirm that the `fileQueue` is being filled and it seems to be getting filled with the correct number of elements, but it seems that only a few elements are actually pulled off of the queue and sent and whats worse is that some files are being repeated in the queue. For example, the last file in the set that I'm reading in seems to be pushed to the queue multiple times. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place I would put a new dict object for each file onto the queue, rather than reusing the same dict instance over and over. Also, you need to signal that no more items will be put onto the queue, e.g. by putting `None`:

```
for filename in lst:
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        roke_data = dict(filename=filename, byte_string=f.read())
        self.fileQueue.put(roke_data)
self.fileQueue.join()
self.fileQueue.put(None)  # the kill pill
```

Second, I can't see any loop in your consumer thread method. You are just getting a single item. Is your code snippet missing something? Have a look at [this example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.join) to see how elements can be consumed from a Queue.

It breaks down to a loop and a blocking call to `get()`:

```
def run(self):
    self.connect_socket() #connects to a socket on localhost
    while True:
        roke_data = self.fileQueue.get()  # blocking!
        if roke_data is None:
            break
        print("Sending file: ", roke_data["filename"])
        self.sc.send(roke_data["byte_string"])
        # Assuming it's a JoinableQueue
        self.fileQueue.task_done()
```

Comment: Yes there is a loop in my `run()` method my bad for forgetting that. The problem ended up being that I was reusing the same dict instance. I was under the impression that once it was passed to the message queue it essentially made a copy of the dict, thus allowing me to reuse it. I didn't know that it would still reference the original dict. Thanks for pointing that out to me.